# OWIN Middleware does not respect JSON Serialization Settings

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, serialization, owin, owin-middleware

I am changing the serialization setting on a Self Hosted OWIN WebAPI 2 application.
All controllers and filters responses are working 100% but any responses from the middleware is not respecting the serialization settings.

How does one set serialization settings on Middleware components?

Below is the configuration in the Startup class.

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

appBuilder.Use<GlobalExceptionMiddleware>();

appBuilder.UseWebApi(config)
```

Comment: Do you understand why this is happening? I am facing the same issue!